# Make image fill free space in text and image container

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a div element with predefined size and a string of content which i render using react-html-parser:

```
const string = `
   some text
   <br />
   some text some text some text some text <b>some bold text</b> some text some text some text some text
   <br />
   <img src='https://i.gifer.com/68UQ.gif' />
`
```

There's always only one image and it can be the top, bottom or middle element. I am trying to make an image, if it is present, take as much space (both vertically or horizontally, without breaking ratio), as possible.
Technically, this code explains my goal, but I guess **img** doesn't care much about flex?

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: start;
   img {
      flex-shrink: 1;
      flex-grow: 1;
   }
}
```

It works fine, if I wrap **img** in a **div** and do this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}
.image-wrapper {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xafwj1Lh/2/

But I really want to avoid parsing a string to wrap an img. Also it's hella ugly.
Is it possible to achieve without any additional html element?

Comment: Without the extra wrapper, have you tried setting with height/width to 100% as well as the max? `img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
`

Comment: Yes, the image just stretches as wide as possible (breaking the ratio if the container is too wide) and the container becomes overflowed if there's any text after the image.